# Get the base class type

Tags: c#, class, types

I believe the name of the Post does not have much with the question but I could not express better

I have the following classes:

```
public class BuyAction
{
    public Deals Deals{ get; set; }
}

public class SellAction
{
    public Deals Deals { get; set; }
}

public class Deals
{
    public int GetDealValueByType(object obj)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof (BuyAction))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof (SellAction))
        {
            return 2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var action = new BuyAction();
        var dealValue = action.Deals.GetDealValueByType(action);
    }
```

My question:
How do I return the dealValue without passing parameters to method "GetDealValueByType"?

Comment: This does not make sense. You've defined the classes so that any user of your classes can copy the `Deals` object from a `BuyAction` to a `SellAction`. If you give the users of your classes that freedom, the `Deals` object cannot possibly hope to tell you what you want it to tell you.

Comment: Why don't you start by explaining what you are trying to do, not how.

Comment: Excuse me for not knowing how to explain and create a class pointless. I have created now just to learn how get the type of the class above.

In my case, I have a condition inside the method that would be the "GetActionClassType". Depending on which is the class that is using it, I will have a different return. But i dont want to pass parameters. Is how to do this?

PS: I edited the main question so that it is easier to visualize.

Comment: it is a bit hard to understand what you want to achieve, but your design is probably wrong as previously stated. If the `GetActionClassType` is something relevant to the Buy and Sell actions, then place the method there and forget about `Deals`

Answer (score 1):

Try using generics :

```
public class BaseAction{} 

public class BuyAction : BaseAction
{
    public int Value { get{ return 1; }} 
}

public class SellAction : BaseAction
{
    public int Value { get{ return 2; }}
}

public class Deals<T> where T : BaseAction,  new() 
{
    public int GetDealValue()
    {
        var data = new T();
        return data.Value;
    }
}
```

Then use it as:

```
var deal1 = new Deals<BuyAction>();
var value1 = deal1.GetDealValue();

var deal2 = new Deals<SellAction>();
var value2 = deal2.GetDealValue();
```

Comment: Probably this options is better. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the code as you wrote it, `Deals` doesn't know about the existence of `BuyAction` or `SellAction`, so there's not way for it to know what class is using it. In order to do this, you should communicate with it somehow. This is a way to do it:

```
public abstract class BaseAction
{
    private Deals _deals;
    public Deals Deals 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_deals == null)
                 // this = BuyAction or SellAction, never BaseAction because it's abstract
                _deals = new Deals(this);
            return _deals;
        }
        set
        {
            _deals = value;
        }
    }

}

public class BuyAction : BaseAction { }
public class SellAction : BaseAction { }

public class Deals
{
    private BaseAction _callerAction;
    public Deals(BaseAction caller)
    {
        this._callerAction = caller;
    }

    public int GetDealValueByType()
    {
        if (this._callerAction is BuyAction)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (this._callerAction is SellAction)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BaseAction action = new BuyAction();
    int dealValue = action.Deals.GetDealValueByType();
    // Prints 1
    Console.WriteLine(dealValue);

    action = new SellAction();
    dealValue = action.Deals.GetDealValueByType();
    // Prints 2
    Console.WriteLine(dealValue);
}
```

As you can see, now the `Deals` class requires a `BaseAction` class for it to be instantiated. This way now you force the class to know who is using it, and then you can take decisions in an object oriented way.

Finally, what you are getting is not the base class, it's the caller or container class. In your example, the only base class was `object`.

Comment: The `GetDealValueByType` method defeats the usage of the `Deals` class, I know that is what he asked, but it is still wrong. IF it depends on the type of the Action, then the Actions are the ones that should have the behaviour. A still wrong, but much better solution would be to pass the result directly in the constructor for example

Comment: Of course. I guess there must be more code that justifies the existence of those classes. That's why I tried to stick to his design as much as possible. If he reformulates the problem, probably this answer will be obsolete. :)

Comment: Thank you so much!
You answered my question when you said
"does not know about the existence of BuyAction or SellAction, so there's not way for it to know what class is using it."

This question was more for information. Sorry it was not as useful as expected. :)

Thanks again